# Reactjs not calling onChange callback in child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written a re-usable input component for `url` if a url dont start with `http` then it will be added http in the beginning.

Here you go for the componet

```
import React, {useContext, useCallback} from 'react';


const InputURL = ({ name, onChange, ...rest}) => {


    const sanitizeURLonChange = React.useCallback((value, actionMeta) => {
        if (value.target.value) {
            if (!value.target.value.startsWith('http')) {
                value.target.value = 'http://' + value.target.value
            }
        }

    }, [onChange])


    return (
        <>
           <input
               name={name}
               {...rest}
               onChange={sanitizeURLonChange}
            />
        </>
    );
}

export default InputURL;
```

But when i try to use it in my some component, the `onChange` doesn't work

I try this way

```
<InputURL onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}  />
```

unfortunately the `inputURL` onChange not working anymore, can you please help me in this case?

I want to achieve. if user input url without http, it will add http,

Like i input it `stackoverflow.com/` and then it will return `https://stackoverflow.com/` in Onchange

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the bracket right after the event argument : `{(e)}`. Try like this:

```
<inputURL onChange={(e, val) => console.log(val)}  />
```

also you have to use the onChange you're passing as props:

```
const sanitizeURLonChange = (e, actionMeta) => {
    let newValue = e.target.value
    if (newValue) {
        if (!newValue.startsWith('http')) {
              newValue = "http://" + newValue
            
        }
    }
    setVal(newValue);
    onChange(event, newValue)
}
```

but it seems anyway the onChange you are passing as a props to inputURL is not used anywhere so I am not sure what you want to achieve. Also you are calling the component `inputURL` instead of `InputURL` and first letter uppercase is very important in JSX.

Comment: It's not working still, can you please try again

Comment: can't help more until I don't know what you wanna achieve. You're passing an onChange prop you are not using, having it in a useEffect that doesn't make much sense... I think you have to reconsider what you want to achieve and explain it more clearly.

Comment: I want to achieve. if user input url without http, it will add http, 

Like i input it `stackoverflow.com/` and then it will return `https://stackoverflow.com/` in Onchange

Comment: check my correction

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here:

```
value.target.value = 'http://' + value.target.value
```

You are trying to update input `value` by not using an hook.

Try to rewrite your code in this way:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';


const InputURL = ({ name, onChange, ...rest}) => {
    const [val, setVal] = useState("");

    const sanitizeURLonChange = (value, actionMeta) => {
        if (value.target.value) {
            if (!value.target.value.startsWith('http')) {
                setVal('http://' + value.target.value);
            }
            else setVal(value.target.value);
        }
    }


    return (
        <>
           <input
               name={name}
               {...rest}
               value={val}
               onChange={sanitizeURLonChange}
            />
        </>
    );
}

export default InputURL;
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/controlled-input-with-react-hooks-forked-lmf2zl?file=/src/index.js) codesandbox working example.

Comment: It doesnt work, you didnt tested it

Comment: @anamul I missed the else statement. Now is working =)